# Get customer names and emails from magento database

Tags: mysql, magento

I am trying to get all names and emails from our customers in magento.

I have the following code, but I am not sure how to get the email

```
SELECT entity_id, GROUP_CONCAT( VALUE
SEPARATOR  ' ' ) AS fullname
FROM customer_address_entity_varchar AS val
INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS attr ON attr.attribute_id = val.attribute_id
WHERE attr.attribute_code
IN (
'firstname',  'lastname',  'email'
)
GROUP BY entity_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Any sample data set plus desired result set ?

Comment: please see screenhot in the comment below the answer, I want name and email thats it, but below sql code does not seem correct

Comment: I would really try my best if you can provide sample dataset here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Email's are stored in the `customer_entity` table, not an eav table.

Try this query instead:

```
select ce.entity_id, concat(cevf.value, ' ', cevl.value) fullname, ce.email
from customer_entity ce
inner join customer_entity_varchar cevf
    on ce.entity_id = cevf.entity_id
inner join eav_attribute eaf
    on eaf.attribute_id = cevf.attribute_id
inner join customer_entity_varchar cevl
    on ce.entity_id = cevl.entity_id
inner join eav_attribute eal
    on eal.attribute_id = cevl.attribute_id
inner join eav_entity_type eet
    on eet.entity_type_id = eal.entity_type_id = eaf.entity_type_id
where
    eet.entity_type_code = 'customer'
    and eaf.attribute_code = 'firstname'
    and eal.attribute_code = 'lastname'
order by ce.entity_id
```

---

In case this interests you, this can be done through PHP with Magento's factory methods

```
<?php

include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$customerCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname');
echo $customerCollection->getSelect();
// foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) print_r($customer->getData());
```

Which will give you something like

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_firstname`.`value` AS `firstname`, `at_lastname`.`value` AS `lastname` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_firstname` ON (`at_firstname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_firstname`.`attribute_id` = '5')
 INNER JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_lastname` ON (`at_lastname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_lastname`.`attribute_id` = '7') WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') AND (at_firstname.value = '') AND (at_lastname.value = '')
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the joins, can you help? I know from heart that the name for nancy@ in the screenshot below is not correct. http://screencast.com/t/XqlSN9AZli